# How to solve this composite function?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to do this question.

Refer the mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x + 1, x + y)$ and
$g(x,y) = 2x + y$.
How do I find $(f \circ g)(2,3)$?

Comment: $f\circ g$ is not well-defined. Do you mean $g\circ f$? (Yeah, it's the "wrong way around". But that's the price we pay for writing functions to the left of their argument.)

Comment: You need co-domain for $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to define composition.

Comment: Refer the definition of composition function then you can get what' wrong here

Comment: @Nath well, please show your progress, and the source of the problem ( if you know ) or else, you get downvotes .. 
Ps: nice profile pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions don't compose that way. $(f \circ g)(x,y)$ is $f(g(x,y))$ but the codomain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$ while the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If you meant $(g \circ f)$, then $(g \circ f)(2,3) = g(f(2,3)) = g(3,5) = 11$